# Next.js, Reactで表示文字を変更したい

Tags: next.js, reactjs

表示データをtitleという変数に持たせて、ボタンがクリックされたらchangeTitleでタイトルを変更させているのですが、変数の中身が変更しても、表示上で変わりません。

なにをすれば表示も変わるのでしょうか？

```js
import type { NextPage } from 'next'

const Account: NextPage = () => {
  let title = "Title";

  function chnageTitle() {
    title = "Changed Title"
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <button onClick={chnageTitle}>Change Title</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Account;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useState` [フック](https://ja.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) が利用できるかと思います。

```
import type { NextPage } from "next";
import { useState } from "react";

const Account: NextPage = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("Title");

  function chnageTitle() {
    setTitle("Change title");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <button onClick={chnageTitle}>Change Title</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Account;
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
うまく動作しました。